# What is this ' +°" ' direction?

Tags: notation, terminology, angle

I have looked all over google for this and I cannot find it because I don't know what it is called, but here is an example:

Azimuth: +283°14'39"

What is this called? Also, is this some way to convey a direction precisely?

Comment: $^o $' "  means degrees, minutes, seconds

Comment: Cf. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(angle)#Subdivisions)

Comment: Like an hour , a degree has $60$ minutes and a minute $60$ seconds (same way as it is defined for the time)

Comment: And the conversion goes just like in the case of time: $283°14'39"=(283+14/60+39/3600)°$.

Comment: Oh so it's saying its going to be at n direction in degrees at this point of time?

Comment: @StocksAndStonks No, it has nothing to do with time, per se.  It's just that an angle has $60$ minutes, and a minute has $60$ seconds, just like time measurement.  (You'll be able to guess why if you think about it for a moment.)  The given azimuth is just an angle.

Comment: According to Wikipedia [Azimuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuth) "An azimuth is an angular measurement in a spherical coordinate system."